# Ассемблер: перехват NumLock

Tags: ассемблер

Здраствуйте!

Мне нужно при нажатии `NumLock` в консоли выводить "1". Но проблема в том, что когда я читаю символы с помощью `int 16h`:

```
mov ah,10h  
int 16h
```

Программа ждет нажатия клавиши, а когда я нажимаю `Numlock`, то прога продолжает ожидать нажатия клавиш...

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии 1 выводилось 1, а при нажатии Numlock - 2?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 5):

Функция `10h` с прерыванием `int 16h` проверяет наличие символа в буфере клавиатуры, но клавиши num lock, caps lock, scroll lock, ctrl, shift... не заносятся в буфер клавиатуры. Для того что бы определить нажат ли NumLock можно использовать функцию `12h` и прерывание `16h`, она вернёт в регистр `AL` состояние клавиатуры.

```
Бит    Название клавиши  
0      левый Ctrl  
1      Левый Alt  
2      Правый ctrl  
3      Правый alt   
4      ScrollLock   
5      NumLock  
6      Caps Lock  
7      SysReq
```

Comment: спасибо....
а как сделать програмно простейшую задержку на 10 мс? везде пишут о 86h int 15h, но у меня почему то не работает. Вот кусок кода:

      mov ah,09h
      mov dx,offset msg_1
      int 21h
      
      ;call delay
      mov cx,0ffffh
      mov dx,0ffffh 
      mov ah,86h 
      int 15h
      
      mov ah,09h
      mov dx,offset msg_1
      int 21h  

теоретически интервал между выводом сообщений должен быть большым, но никакого интервала нет...

Comment: попробуй числа поменьше взять 

    xor   cx,cx
    mov   dx,20000

Или дебагером посмотри, может функция возвращает ошибку(надо по флагам смотреть вроде)?